# Posting data in excel from one sheet to the next using formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am designing a form which captures data for students fees payment. I now want this data to be posted on individual students sheets. I want the information to be posted one after the other in the individual students sheets through a formula. Currently the information from the master sheet is being posted but not one after the other in the individual students sheets. If the transaction is in for example cell A5 in the master sheet in the individual student sheet it is also posted in cell A5 with cells A!, A2, A3, A4 which are blank. I would like this transaction to be posted to cell A1.

Comment: Use FILTER() if you have Office 365 Excel

Comment: Could you please share us with simple sample? Thx ~